# AVG COUNT Query

Tags: sql, dml

I am trying to do a query but I don´t know how to do it.

These are the tables:

```
  Table Hospital         Table Doctor      Table Work

  Hid    Country         ic                Hid     ic
   1     England          1                 1       1
   2     Spain            2                 1       2
   3     France           3                 1       3  
   4     England          4                 2       4
   5     China            5                 4       5
```

Result that I want:

```
  Country     Average of Doctors Working on that Hospitals of that Country
  England     2 (the doctor with ic 1, 2, 3, and 4/number of hid)
  Spain       1
  France      0
  China       0
```

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT H.country, AVG(D.ic) 
FROM Hospital H, Doctor D 
WHERE H.hid IN 
      ( SELECT W.hid 
        FROM Work W 
        WHERE W.ic IN 
              ( SELECT COUNT(D.ic) 
                FROM D Doctor .... 
              ) 
      ) 
GROUP BY(H.country);
```

Comment: Can you please share you query?

Comment: I see one doctor in Spain, not in China.

Comment: Your attempt is more complex than needed. Try to count the number of doctors per country and the number of hospitals per country. The average you want is then only the division between these two numbers.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this question also as it is a bit more complex then I first thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select H.Country, count(W.ic) / count(distinct H.hid) as [Average]
from Hospital as H
    left outer join Work as W on W.Hid = H.Hid
group by H.Country
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4224/3)

Answer (score 0):

First get the number of doctors for each hospital, then get the average over that:

```
select country, avg(docs) as avg_doctors_working
from (
      select country, h.hid, count(*) as docs,
      from hospital h
    left join work w on w.hid = h.hid
    group by 1, 2) x
group by 1;
```